# Can I use PCI SATA Addon card and Boot from a HDD attached to the card

Tags: hard-drive, boot, sata, pci

Can I boot from a HDD which is running from a PCI SATA expansion card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long at the BIOS on both the SATA card and on your motherboard support it, then yes you should be able to boot from it.  Most SATA and motherboard BIOS' do support this these days.

You may/will have to adjust the boot order in your motherboard BIOS setup to get the expansion card to boot first.

Comment: My 3 year old MB is Asus M2N-MX and the BIOS is not upgraded since i had it should i upgrade it where can i find a trusty upgrade. can u recommend any PCI addon brand with boot capability. Any Global Brand.

Comment: You can get any Asus BIOS updates from support.asus.com. As for a recommended SATA controller, there are lots to choose from, and none I'd specifically recommend. I used to suggest a specific Promise card for straight SATA, but it seems they've dropped everything that isn't a RAID-enabled card. Still probably worth checking them out (www.promise.com).